# Is there a way to make Ruby edit .js files before they are served?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to write something (in Ruby) that will automatically add console.log() to each line of my javascript assets before serving it to the user. This tool would aid me greatly in my debugging efforts of large js files by saving time and giving me a back-trace. I know rails has all sorts of built-in helpers... Maybe a before_serve ? I know sprockets mashes the files together before serving them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
if Rails.env.development?
  Sprockets::Server.module_eval do
    alias_method :ok_response_orig, :ok_response
    def ok_response(asset, env)
      asset.instance_eval do
        #The next string to be appended
        @source += %{
        \n;(function(){
            console.log("Called from #{File.basename(@pathname)}");
          })();
          }
        @length = Rack::Utils.bytesize(@source)
        @digest = Digest::MD5.new.update(@source).hexdigest
      end if asset.instance_eval{@pathname.to_s}.include?(".js") #You might want to add .coffee here
      ok_response_orig(asset, env)
    end
    def etag_match?(*args)
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Enjoy.
P.S. Use it only in development env.

Comment: TY! Where do you think is the best place to put this? I'd ultimately like to make this into a gem..

Comment: You may want to put it in the config/initializers/sprockets.rb file.